# Opening application via Jumplist breaks Prism module dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, prism

I'm new to .Net and WPF and I am developing something using Prism that exhibits strange behavior when I attempt to open the app via a JumpTask. My app.xaml.cs uses this to open the shell:

```
Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
bootstrapper.Run();
Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
```

Bootstrapper is:

```
public class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();

        this.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly));
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        return new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
    }

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return this.Container.GetExportedValue<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

I also add a module in my app.config:

```
<module assemblyFile=".\EventsModule.dll" moduleType="EventsModule.Events" moduleName="Events" startupLoaded="true" />
```

Everything works as it should if I don't use the JumpTask item, but I receive an exception if I do - this is what is confusing me.

The JumpTask is created by this:

```
private void CreateJumpList()
    {
            JumpList jl = JumpList.GetJumpList(App.Current);

            if (jl == null)
            {
                jl = new JumpList();
                JumpList.SetJumpList(App.Current, jl);
            }

            JumpTask newQLTask = new JumpTask();
            newQLTask.Title = "Test";
            newQLTask.CustomCategory = Properties.Resources.JumpList_Recents;
            newQLTask.ApplicationPath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;

            jl.JumpItems.Add(newQLTask);

            jl.Apply();                       
    }
```

The exception information is summarised below:

> Source       : Prism.Wpf
>
> Method       : HandleModuleTypeLoadingError
>
> Type         : Prism.Modularity.ModuleTypeLoadingException
>
> Error        : Failed to load type for module Events.
>
> Error was: Could not load file or assembly 'EventsModule.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the path specified..
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'EventsModule.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
>
> Stack Trace  : at Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.HandleModuleTypeLoadingError(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, Exception exception)
>
> at Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.IModuleTypeLoader_LoadModuleCompleted(Object sender, LoadModuleCompletedEventArgs e)
>
> at Prism.Mef.Modularity.MefFileModuleTypeLoader.RaiseLoadModuleCompleted(LoadModuleCompletedEventArgs e)
>
> at Prism.Mef.Modularity.MefFileModuleTypeLoader.LoadModuleType(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
>
> at Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.BeginRetrievingModule(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
>
> at Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.LoadModuleTypes(IEnumerable`1 moduleInfos)
>
> at Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.LoadModulesWhenAvailable()
>
> at Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.Run()
>
> at Prism.Mef.MefBootstrapper.InitializeModules()
>
> at Prism.Mef.MefBootstrapper.Run(Boolean runWithDefaultConfiguration)
>
> at Prism.Bootstrapper.Run()
>
> at App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
>
> at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
>
> at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>
> at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

I have tried to use FUSLOGVW but no errors relating to this issue are there.

Any help or information to further my education in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `newQLTask.WorkingDirectory` to the path where your exe lives? Just a guess on my part. Seems like that would help the application to know where everything is when it starts.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much, I feel silly for not looking into that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to R.Richards comment, adding newQLTask.WorkingDirectory to the exe directory resolved the issue.